# Duplicate symbol _main: linker command failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker

My single view, iPad iOS 7 Landscape view app has a build failed and this is the error message...

```
Ld /Users/Angus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mineplex_Forums-dufpnpqqzcrvjdfuogyvvdoflzrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mineplex\ Forums.app/Mineplex\ Forums normal i386
    cd "/Users/Angus/Documents/xCode/Mineplex Forums"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/Angus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mineplex_Forums-dufpnpqqzcrvjdfuogyvvdoflzrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Angus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mineplex_Forums-dufpnpqqzcrvjdfuogyvvdoflzrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/Angus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mineplex_Forums-dufpnpqqzcrvjdfuogyvvdoflzrt/Build/Intermediates/Mineplex\ Forums.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mineplex\ Forums.build/Objects-normal/i386/Mineplex\ Forums.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Angus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mineplex_Forums-dufpnpqqzcrvjdfuogyvvdoflzrt/Build/Intermediates/Mineplex\ Forums.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mineplex\ Forums.build/Objects-normal/i386/Mineplex\ Forums_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Angus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mineplex_Forums-dufpnpqqzcrvjdfuogyvvdoflzrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mineplex\ Forums.app/Mineplex\ Forums

duplicate symbol _main in:
    /Users/Angus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mineplex_Forums-dufpnpqqzcrvjdfuogyvvdoflzrt/Build/Intermediates/Mineplex Forums.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mineplex Forums.build/Objects-normal/i386/MinigamesMenu.o
    /Users/Angus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mineplex_Forums-dufpnpqqzcrvjdfuogyvvdoflzrt/Build/Intermediates/Mineplex Forums.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mineplex Forums.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Not quite sure how to fix this, because I am new to iOS development, and this all seems like 20 lines of gibberish to me.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a file called MinigamesMenu with a function called `main`, and you have another `main` function in your main.m file.  You have to rename the main function in MinigamesMenu.

Comment: this is the only thing that I could find...           `int main() {
    
    for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", family);
        
        for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
        {
            NSLog(@"  %@", name);
        }
    }
 `

Comment: You will have to rename that function.

Comment: I have created a new integer in my MinigamesMenu.h I called it "FontTest" then back to that code above I removed the "main", and I replaced it with "FontTest", and I'm getting this error... "Redefinition of 'FontTest' as different kind of symbol", how do I fix this??

Comment: Now you have a function and variable with the same name.  You will have to rename either your FontTest integer or your FontTest function.  2 things cannot have the same name.

Comment: Okay, I replaced the "FontTest" from the above code with "Font", and now on my final "{" I'm getting an error saying...  "control reaches end of non-void function"

Comment: Change `int Font()` to `void Font()`.

Comment: One last question, I have run my program, and it works fine, however I'm trying to find the name of my font in the log, but nothing shows up in the log, I've done every step to put it in the project plist, etc

Comment: Are you calling your function?

Comment: For your function to run, you have to call it.  In the code you want to run your function, just type `Font();`

Comment: Ok this is now what this snippet of code looks like... `void Font() {
    
    Font();
    
    for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", family);
        
        for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
        {
            NSLog(@"  %@", name);
        }
    }
    
}`

Comment: But all I get in the log is this... "2014-04-08 09:29:31.499 Mineplex Forums[5692:60b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x8f9c830 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)" Any thoughts?

Comment: First of all, that log message is a common little glitch in Xcode, and it isn't really anything to worry about, and second, that's not what I meant.  Remove that new line from your Font() function, and add it to your `AppDelegate`'s `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.  Then you need to find a good tutorial because you're a bit confused how functions work.

Comment: In your `AppDelegate.m` file.